# calling an operator overloaded function from another operator overloaded function: performance

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm making a fraction class for study purposes. In order to add to functions I overloaded the + operator. The first one takes a fraction as 2nd parameter and the second function takes an int as 2nd parameter. Although it's possible to call one of the functions from the other, is it a good practice regarding performance?

```
Fraction Fraction::operator+(const Fraction& r_oper) {                                                                   
    int l_lcm{Fberlanga::Math::lcm(this->denominator(),r_oper.denominator())};                                           
    Fraction fr(l_lcm*this->numerator() / this->denominator() + l_lcm*r_oper.numerator() / r_oper.denominator(),l_lcm);  
    fr.simplify();                                                                                                       
    return fr;                                                                                                           
}

Fraction Fraction::operator+(int r_oper) {                                                                               
    Fraction fr{r_oper,1}; // create fraction of the form r_oper / 1                                                                                               
    fr = (*this) + fr;  // call the other version that takes a fraction as 2nd parameter                                                                                              
    //fr.simplify(); no need, it simplifies when calls the other function                                                                                                       
    return fr;                                                                                                           
}
```

Comment: Only a profiling the code can tell you whether or not performance is an issue, but I can tell you code that doesn't exist contains no bugs.

Comment: I tested it and works fine. I just would like to know of any performance impact when calling one version of the function from the other, instead of implementing the 2nd function without calling the first one

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to see the compiler automatically inline the call. If you do not mind an implicit constructor, you could define `Fraction::Fraction(int)` and remove your definition for `Fraction::operator+(int)` completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its definitely sub-optimal, but this type of code structure is a common practice, although my personal opinion is that it's not a good decision in this case.

Regarding performance:

A rewrite would probably look something like:

```
Fraction Fraction::operator+(int r_oper) {
    Fraction fr(this->numerator() + this->denominator() * r_oper, this->denominator());
//    fr.simplify(); <-- Even this is redundant!!!
    return fr;
}
```

This is a significantly simpler logic, and I highly doubt any compiler can optimize away all the relevant parts.

The downside might be that if you change your structure or logic somehow you'd have to modify 2 functions instead of 1. However, considering the involved complexity (rewriting will probably be a very simple affair) I'd go with a verbose / optimized version in this case.

P.S. If you decide to stick with your version, the `int` version can return `(*this) + fr` without simplyifing and without assignment;

Comment: I think "It's definitely sub-optimal" is a vacuous claim. It lacks any basis in evidence. I think for any reasonable Fraction (rational?) implementation the compiler _will_ inline the code to be completely equivalent. In fact I think all the major operations in Boost Multiprecision and Boost Rational have been implemented in this way. I can assure you these people have looked at the generated code in all popular compilers. See also http://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: @sehe - My claim is not based on (lack-of) obvious inline candidate. It's "based" on the fact that the compiler (to my understanding) won't be able to optimize away everything involved in the calculation (least common, various multiplication & division) that are 100% redundant due to the denominator being 1.

Comment: Eh. You have a point there. I haven't read it closely enough it appears. Mmm. Yes. If the branch is structurally simpler, have a separate implementation, makes sense. +1

Comment: @sehe - Easy finger on the trigger... Happens to all of us :-)

Comment: I know that this can be optimized by eliminating some redundancies. That's not my point. What are the pros and cons of this excluding the common mistakes of redundancies.

Comment: @blade - well then you managed to distract me. If you're question is solely regarding the code structure then as others and myself claimed, there will most likely be no difference at all since you'll (likely) get automatic inlining.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is: maybe.

If you are using compiler inlining, then it is probally just as fast. You do that by either declaring the `operator` inside the class declaration or using the `inline` declarator before the return type when declaring the variable:

```
class Fraction
{
    ....
    inline operator+(...);
    ....
};
```

Note, if you are using inlining, the definition MUST be in the header file.

If you are using linking (putting the function in the .cpp file), then there is no way it is as fast, because linking to a function adds a slight overhead.

Either way that you are using, is is still highly suggested to call the operator inside the other operator because it is much more readable, more maintainable, and less physical code.

Comment: The answer is almost definitely not maybe. See my answer. I'd love to see an explanation of how inlining and / or optimization can make that "just as fast"

Comment: i agree. I'm saying if you dont use inline it won't be as fast.